Understanding the contents of rmtab
man mountd states:
   The rmtab File
       The rpc.mountd daemon registers every successful MNT request by adding
       an entry  to  the  /var/lib/nfs/rmtab file. When receivng a UMNT request
       from an NFS client, rpc.mountd simply removes the matching entry from
       /var/lib/nfs/rmtab, as long as the access control list for that export
       allows that sender to access the  export.

       (...)

Here is an excerpt from my (Ubuntu 22.04) server:
10.51.84.22:/srv/data:0x00000049
10.51.38.38:/srv/data:0x00000002
10.51.39.104:/srv/data:0x00000003

It seems obvious what the first and second column contain, but what does the hex value describe?

Hi,
please, can you specify which os/version are you using? Because this may be important to provide a good answer

@sigmud My server is running Ubuntu 22.04. I have updated the question.

I apologize: my google-foo is vary bad: I could not find any info about the third field in the  rmtab file format - my best suggestion is to download and read the source code
